# jQuery Move div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to move .link-field-first-ticket-button inside .event-location-one

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksV73/

It's a cms so I have no choice in the matter.

this is what I'm trying, it's not doing much of anything

```
$(".widget-upcoming-events-blog li").each( function() {
     var links = $(this).children(".link-field-first-ticket-button").html();
     $(this).children(".link-field-first-ticket-button").html("");
     $(this).children(".event-location-one").append(links);
});
```

Answer (score 36):

You can just do this:

```
$(".link-field-first-ticket-button").appendTo(".event-location-one");
```

It will move the first ticket button to event location

Comment: Nice and simple, lovely

Comment: It's really clean and simple! Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = $(".widget-upcoming-events-blog").find(".link-field-first-ticket-button").remove()
$(".event-location-one").append(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `html` method will give you the content inside the element, not the element itself.

Just append the element where you want it. As an element can't exist in two places at once, it will be moved:

```
$(".widget-upcoming-events-blog li").each( function() {
  var links = $(this).children(".link-field-first-ticket-button");
  $(this).children(".event-location-one").append(links);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(".widget-upcoming-events-blog li").each( function() {
     var links = $(".link-field-first-ticket-button").html();
     $(".link-field-first-ticket-button").html("");
     $(".event-location-one").append(links);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.children()` to `.find()`

```
$(".widget-upcoming-events-blog li").each( function() {
     var links = $(this).find(".link-field-first-ticket-button").html();
     $(this).find(".link-field-first-ticket-button").html("");
     $(this).find(".event-location-one").append(links);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about use the `.appendTo()` function?

For example:

```
$(".widget-upcoming-events-blog li").each( function() {
 $(this).find(".link-field-first-ticket-button")
        .appendTo( $(this).find(".event-location-one") );
});
```

Comment: Guy. You saved my life :) Thanks. The other methods were duplicating my button on the site for some reason, even though they work on the fiddle